# System.IO.Compression.ZipFile Multiple Directories

Tags: powershell, zip, compression

I can get this to work if I set up an array for my `$destination` but this creates a seperate .zip for each directory selected.

How can I select every directory and zip them under a single destination instead of multiple destination files? Here is my code:

```
$type = "*.txt"
$destination = "LogsBackup.zip"

Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ;

$_sources = dir c:\Logs\$type -Recurse | Select Directory -Unique | 
            Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple |
            Select @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.Directory -As [string]}} 

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $_sources.Length; $i++)
{
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory( $_sources[$i].Path , $destination)
}
```

I want to keep my `Out-GridView` option the way it is so if it's a single directory or multiple I can select them and store them as an array.

Comment: if you are on Powershell v5 this can be done pretty easily.

Comment: Yes its powershell v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-update` parameter will make sure that your existing archive is updated with new entries that you select from `out-gridview`.

```
$destination = "C:\logs\LogsBackup.zip"

#Create a single archive
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\logs -Filter *.txt -Recurse | 
    Select @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.DirectoryName}} -Unique  | 
        Out-GridView -PassThru | Compress-Archive -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath $destination -Update
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am wanting except I want it to create the Archive if it does not exist. I'm sure its a parameter flag but I'm not 100% sure on to make this happen.

Comment: Okay I think I got it working now but how do I show more than just the directory path in the gridview. I want to also show the directory contents.

Comment: Its working now. I did just realize that not all users I will distributing this script to use from our company will have version 5. Is there an equivalent for version 4?

Comment: Will do Thank you!