# Looking for a script that takes files and zips them into a bundle

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip, code-cleanup

I'm trying to make a powershell script that grabs certain files and or folders and zips them up automatically to make my techs reimages faster

We have to grab the zips and or folders from certain locations to back them up before reimaging a system. Can anyone help on this?

I'm pretty new to Powershell.

```
Param(
    [string]$FilesLocation,
    [string]$BackupPath,
    $Days
)

$CurrentTime = "\" + (get-date -f MM_dd_yyyy) + "_" + (get-date -f HH_mm) + "_Backup_"
#$BackupPath = $BackupPath+$CurrentTime

$BackupPath
$Name = $CurrentTime + ".zip"

$ArchiveFile = Join-Path -Path $BackupPath -ChildPath $Name
If (Test-path $ArchiveFile) {Remove-item $ArchiveFile}

Get-ChildItem -Path $FilesLocation - |
    Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-date).AddDays(-1)} |

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($FilesLocation, $ArchiveFile)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Sorry didnt see this comment

what I'm trying to do is not necessarily by date but i need to grab certain folders all together or just even certain files So how would i take that one and add more than one file or even folders and have them zipped at the end

Ill have to add a progress bar sooner or later

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked fine for me.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
$logFolder=Read-Host "enter foldername (eg=c:/temp)"
$zipFileName=Read-Host "enter a name for zip file (eg=filename.zip)" 
$finalPath=$logFolder+"/"+$zipFileName
Write-Host $finalPath
$startDate=Read-Host "enter date in the format mm/dd/yyyy" 
$endDate=Read-Host "enter date in the format mm/dd/yyyy"
# creates empty zip file:
[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive] $archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($finalPath,[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update)
# add your files to archive
Get-ChildItem -path $logFolder | foreach {[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($archive,$_.FullName,$_.Name)}
# archive will be updated with files after you close it. normally, in C#, you would use "using ZipArchvie arch = new ZipFile" and object would be disposed upon exiting "using" block. here you have to dispose manually:
$archive.Dispose()
```

It will create the zip for all the files available at `$logFolder`.

Comment: and I'm assuming that 

   `finalPath=$logFolder+"/"+$zipFileName`



"/" is the destination of where the zip is saved or do i still have to 





`$Destination = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop"`    ???

Comment: Now if I run it flashes and goes away if I copy all that's in the .ps1 it runs whats in there and gives errors

here's what I have in the .ps1

and how do I add another file or folder to $logFolder=Read-Host


https://pastebin.com/DENbqLR1

Comment: Yes `$finalPath` is the path for zip file

Comment: You can put all files and folder in one folder and then you can give the path for that main folder.

Comment: You have to include the assembly for `[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]`. Add
`Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"` on the top of your script

Comment: Sorry was at work and just checked this let me try it now

Comment: Ok so if if I wanted to put multiple paths how would I do that

Comment: Well for one path it will create one zip file. In that case you can put this in a function and can pass the path as parameter. So each time when you call this function, it will create a separate zip file for that particular path.

Comment: You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347813/7552582)
 @kiran has given a very good explanation on this.